# Are all the function properties actually invoked in React to lift the state up the component tree?

Tags: reactjs

We have a child component:

```
export default function Star({ selected = false, onSelect = (f) => f }) {
  return <FaStar color={selected ? "red" : "grey"} onClick={onSelect} />;
}
```

and a parent component:

```
export default function StarRating({
  totalStars = 5,
  selectedStars = 0,
  onRate = (f) => f
}) {
  return (
    <>
      {createArray(totalStars).map((n, i) => (
        <Star
          key={i}
          selected={selectedStars > i}
          onSelect={() => onRate(i + 1)}
        />
      ))}
      <p>
        {selectedStars} of {totalStars} stars
      </p>
    </>
  );
}
```

Is the onSelect function property actually invoked when the onClick is triggered, or it is just a variable that helps to set onClick equal to () => onRate(i + 1)?

Like this:

```
let onClick;
let onSelect;
onSelect = () => onRate(i + 1);
onClick = onSelect;
```

Comment: This seems like an easy thing to test yourself. Do you think it should be called, and it's not?

Comment: I`m just curious how it works. By invoking onClick do we actually invoke onSelect or we directly invoke the anonymous function that onSelect is set equal to in the parent component.

Comment: I honestly don't understand your question. in your exact code `onClick` will invoke the function that you pass to it, so `() => onRate(i + 1)`